# root@[IP address] でcreateすると

Tags: mysql

root@[IP address] でcreateすると

Access denied for user 'root'@'[IP address]' to database 'l'

のエラーが出るのはなぜですか？

Comment: see also; https://teratail.com/questions/297642 コンピュータは１文字でも違ったら動かない代物なので「正確なログ」がないと妄想と憶測で答えることになってお互いに時間の無駄に終わります。

Comment: 外部接続ユーザはデフォルトでは作成できないはずです。何らかの方法でユーザを作ったはずですので、今回ユーザを作った時のSQLおよび付与した権限のSQL、および接続の際に実行したコマンドや実際に流し込んだCreate文のSQLを記載してください。